# configure: error: Mesos requires Python < 3.0

Tags: python, mesos

I want to install **Mesos** on Oracle Linux 8.3 which does not have Internet access. I followed the process exactly in its site in part `CentOS 7.1` and installed some packages before building mesos. I installed these packages using `rpm -i name of package`:

```
glib2-2.56.4-156.el8.x86_64.rpm
glib2-2.56.4-8.el8.x86_64.rpm
glib2-devel-2.56.4-156.el8.x86_64.rpm
glib2-devel-2.56.4-8.el8.x86_64.rpm
libcurl-7.61.1-14.el8.x86_64.rpm
libcurl-devel-7.61.1-14.el8.x86_64.rpm
libsecret-devel-0.18.6-1.el8.x86_64.rpm
libserf-1.3.9-9.module_el8.4.0+632+d2bf8782.x86_64.rpm
pcre-8.42-4.el8.x86_64.rpm
pcre-cpp-8.42-4.el8.x86_64.rpm
pcre-devel-8.42-4.el8.x86_64.rpm
pcre-utf16-8.42-4.el8.x86_64.rpm
pcre-utf32-8.42-4.el8.x86_64.rpm
cyrus-sasl-md5-2.1.27-5.el8.x86_64.rpm
python2-2.7.15-24.el8.x86_64.rpm
python2-2.7.18-7.module_el8.5.0+894+1c54b371.x86_64.rpm
python2-devel-2.7.15-24.el8.x86_64.rpm
python2-libs-2.7.15-24.el8.x86_64.rpm
python2-libs-2.7.18-7.module_el8.5.0+894+1c54b371.x86_64.rpm
python2-pip-9.0.3-18.module_el8.4.0+642+1dc4fb01.noarch.rpm
python2-pip-wheel-9.0.3-18.module_el8.5.0+743+cd2f5d28.noarch.rpm
python2-setuptools-wheel-39.0.1-13.module_el8.5.0+743+cd2f5d28.noarch.rpm
sqlite-devel-3.26.0-11.el8.x86_64.rpm
subversion-1.10.2-4.module_el8.3.0+703+ba2f61b7.x86_64.rpm
subversion-devel-1.10.2-4.module_el8.3.0+703+ba2f61b7.x86_64.rpm
subversion-libs-1.10.2-4.module_el8.3.0+703+ba2f61b7.x86_64.rpm
utf8proc-2.1.1-5.module_el8.3.0+703+ba2f61b7.x86_64.rpm
zlib-devel-1.2.11-16.el8_2.x86_64.rpm
```

Also, I installed **python2.7** in this way:

```
 tar zxvf Python-2.7.15.tgz
 ./configure --enable-optimizations
 make altinstall
```

After that I set its path in **~/.bashrc** like this:

```
  alias python=/usr/local/bin/python2.7
  export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/python2.7
```

For its pip also I run this command:

```
  python2.7 -m ensurepip --default-pip
```

When I run `python --version` it show me `Python 2.7.15`.
Again extract **Mesos** folder and create **build** directory, then run `../configure`; but I receive the same error before installing `python 2.7.15`:

```
  configure: error: Mesos requires Python < 3.0
  -------------------------------------------------------------------
  The detected Python version is 3.6.

  If you already have Python 2.6+ installed (and it's the default python on the path), you might want to check if you have the PYTHON environment variable set to a version of Python greater than 3.0.
```

However, when I run `python` command and receive this result which show that `python 2.7.15` is default, mesos recognize `python 3.6`:

```
  Python 2.7.15 (default, Sep 10 2022, 16:33:49)
```

Output of `printenv`:

```
 LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_21_4:/opt/oracle/instantclient_21_4:/opt/oracle/instantclient_21_4:

 LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=38;5;33:ln=38;5;51:mh=00:pi=40;38;5;11:so=38;5;13:do=38;5;5:bd=48;5;232;38;5;11:cd=48;5;232;38;5;3:or=48;5;232;38;5;9:mi=01;05;37;41:su=48;5;196;38;5;15:sg=48;5;11;38;5;16:ca=48;5;196;38;5;226:tw=48;5;10;38;5;16:ow=48;5;10;38;5;21:st=48;5;21;38;5;15:ex=38;5;40:*.tar=38;5;9:*.tgz=38;5;9:*.arc=38;5;9:*.arj=38;5;9:*.taz=38;5;9:*.lha=38;5;9:*.lz4=38;5;9:*.lzh=38;5;9:*.lzma=38;5;9:*.tlz=38;5;9:*.txz=38;5;9:*.tzo=38;5;9:*.t7z=38;5;9:*.zip=38;5;9:*.z=38;5;9:*.dz=38;5;9:*.gz=38;5;9:*.lrz=38;5;9:*.lz=38;5;9:*.lzo=38;5;9:*.xz=38;5;9:*.zst=38;5;9:*.tzst=38;5;9:*.bz2=38;5;9:*.bz=38;5;9:*.tbz=38;5;9:*.tbz2=38;5;9:*.tz=38;5;9:*.deb=38;5;9:*.rpm=38;5;9:*.jar=38;5;9:*.war=38;5;9:*.ear=38;5;9:*.sar=38;5;9:*.rar=38;5;9:*.alz=38;5;9:*.ace=38;5;9:*.zoo=38;5;9:*.cpio=38;5;9:*.7z=38;5;9:*.rz=38;5;9:*.cab=38;5;9:*.wim=38;5;9:*.swm=38;5;9:*.dwm=38;5;9:*.esd=38;5;9:*.jpg=38;5;13:*.jpeg=38;5;13:*.mjpg=38;5;13:*.mjpeg=38;5;13:*.gif=38;5;13:*.bmp=38;5;13:*.pbm=38;5;13:*.pgm=38;5;13:*.ppm=38;5;13:*.tga=38;5;13:*.xbm=38;5;13:*.xpm=38;5;13:*.tif=38;5;13:*.tiff=38;5;13:*.png=38;5;13:*.svg=38;5;13:*.svgz=38;5;13:*.mng=38;5;13:*.pcx=38;5;13:*.mov=38;5;13:*.mpg=38;5;13:*.mpeg=38;5;13:*.m2v=38;5;13:*.mkv=38;5;13:*.webm=38;5;13:*.ogm=38;5;13:*.mp4=38;5;13:*.m4v=38;5;13:*.mp4v=38;5;13:*.vob=38;5;13:*.qt=38;5;13:*.nuv=38;5;13:*.wmv=38;5;13:*.asf=38;5;13:*.rm=38;5;13:*.rmvb=38;5;13:*.flc=38;5;13:*.avi=38;5;13:*.fli=38;5;13:*.flv=38;5;13:*.gl=38;5;13:*.dl=38;5;13:*.xcf=38;5;13:*.xwd=38;5;13:*.yuv=38;5;13:*.cgm=38;5;13:*.emf=38;5;13:*.ogv=38;5;13:*.ogx=38;5;13:*.aac=38;5;45:*.au=38;5;45:*.flac=38;5;45:*.m4a=38;5;45:*.mid=38;5;45:*.midi=38;5;45:*.mka=38;5;45:*.mp3=38;5;45:*.mpc=38;5;45:*.ogg=38;5;45:*.ra=38;5;45:*.wav=38;5;45:*.oga=38;5;45:*.opus=38;5;45:*.spx=38;5;45:*.xspf=38;5;45:

LC_MEASUREMENT=az_IR
M2_HOME=/usr/local/maven
SSH_CONNECTION=x.x.x.x 57648 xx.xx.xx.xx 22
LC_PAPER=az_IR
LC_MONETARY=az_IR
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
HOSTNAME=kr311
OLDPWD=/root/Downloads/mesos/mesos-1.11.0
JAVA_HOME=/opt/oracle/java/jdk1.8.0_25
S_COLORS=auto
LC_NAME=az_IR
XDG_SESSION_ID=2
USER=root
PYSPARK_HOME=/usr/bin/python3.8
SELINUX_ROLE_REQUESTED=
PWD=/root/Downloads/mesos/mesos-1.11.0/build
SSH_ASKPASS=/usr/libexec/openssh/gnome-ssh-askpass
HOME=/root
SSH_CLIENT=x.x.x.x 57648 22
SELINUX_LEVEL_REQUESTED=
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/root/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share:/usr/local/share:/usr/share
LC_ADDRESS=az_IR
SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark
LC_NUMERIC=az_IR
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
MAIL=/var/spool/mail/root
TERM=xterm-256color
SHELL=/bin/bash
SELINUX_USE_CURRENT_RANGE=
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python3.8
SHLVL=1
LC_TELEPHONE=az_IR
LOGNAME=root
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/0/bus
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/0
PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3.8
PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_21_4:/opt/oracle/java/jdk1.8.0_25/bin:/opt/oracle/instantclient_21_4:/usr/local/bin/python2.7:/opt/oracle/java/jdk1.8.0_25/bin:/opt/oracle/instantclient_21_4:/opt/oracle/java/jdk1.8.0_25/bin:/usr/local/maven/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin/python2.7:/opt/spark/bin:/opt/spark/sbin:/root/bin:/opt/spark/bin:/opt/spark/sbin:/usr/local/bin/python2.7:/opt/spark/bin:/opt/spark/sbin

 LC_IDENTIFICATION=az_IR
 HISTSIZE=1000
 LESSOPEN=||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
 LC_TIME=az_IR_=/usr/bin/printenv
```

Would you please guide me what is wrong here?

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: What's the output of `printenv`?

Comment: @pigrammer thank you for your feedback. I add output of ```printenv``` to the end of the question.